# Docker logs show Interactive shell

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I try to execute docker container then it always throw an error that:
Error response from daemon: Container XXX is restarting, wait until the container is running
When I check the log then it show me :
Interactive shell

How can I solve it?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0.33-cli
MAINTAINER Adil 

COPY ./ /var/www/html

COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure mysqli --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN apt-get update
RUN dpkg --configure -a
RUN apt-get install -f
RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
```

Comment: How you are trying to see docker logs?

Comment: docker logs --tail 50 --follow --timestamps web

Comment: `docker logs --follow` will follow log output that's why it may seem like an interactive shell. Use this instead `docker logs --tail 50 --timestamps web`

Comment: Yes I tried it also but main thing is log. Log still display Interactive shell.

Comment: Please, share `docker run` command for `web` container

Comment: docker run --name <app name> --rm -p 4040:80 <image>

Comment: what's the container name when you run `docker ps` ?